# is there a way to render a React component in ERB using <Component/>?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

instead of creating a div with an id and using ReactDOM to render it. For example, I am currently doing this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="home-page"></div>
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Component1 from './components/Component1'

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    <Component1/>
    <Component2/>
  }
}
```

But would prefer to do this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<Component1/>
<Component2/>
```

Is this possible? I am able to do it with Vue.js but it doesn't appear to be possible with react.

Comment: No, because JSX is Javascript, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [react on rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails). It is the closest you will get to. It gives you a `react_component` view helper that allows you to render components previously registered.

Comment: thanks but that's actually what I am migrating away from

Answer (score 0):

if you use something like `react-router` and define a routes jsx file, then you can simply do `<div id="react-router"></div>` in your erb file not sure if this is what you are looking for.